# why if I redirect the STD_OUT on a file and write to STD_OUT the file remains empty?

Tags: c

I can't solve a problem with standard output laugh, I'm on Unix operating system, so the file-descriptor of STD_IN = 0, STD_OUT = 1, STD_ERR = 2, basically I tried to close the descriptor associated with the standard output, and then overwrite it with that of the file I want to write to, but when I open the file it is empty.
CODE:

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<unistd.h>
/*special file's descriptor  --use it or constants in unistd.h-- */
#define STD_IN 0 /*standard input stream*/
#define STD_OUT 1 /*standard output stream*/
#define STD_ERR 2 /*standard output-error stream*/

int main(unsigned int num_of_args, char** args)
{
    if(num_of_args != 3)
    {
        write(STD_ERR, "Few argouments.\nThe use  = ./executable <message> <file>\n", 69);
        return -1;
    }

    int file_des= open(args[2],  O_CREAT,  0640);

    if(file_des < 0)
    {
        write(STD_ERR, "Error, we couldn't open file.\n", 31);
        return -1;
    }

    //I close the descriptor associated with STD_OUT
    close(STD_OUT);

    //I copy the descriptor associated with fil_des on the first available descriptor(so STD_OUT)
    dup(file_des);

    write(STD_OUT, args[1], sizeof(args[1]));

    close(file_des);

    return 0;
}
```

It should be fine, I don't see any errors, but when I open the file I don't find the message written.
Because? help me

Comment: `#define STD_IN 0`?  [POSIX already defines `STDIN_FILENO`, `STDOUT_FILENO`, and `STDERR_FILENO`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html) in `unistd.h`.

Comment: You are hoping that dup will re-use 1, but not checking the return value.

Comment: @stark If `STDOUT_FILENO` or `1` is `close()`d, the lowest numbered available file descriptor will be `1`.  In that case `dup()` [is guaranteed to return `1`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_14): "All functions that open one or more file descriptors shall, unless specified otherwise, atomically allocate the lowest numbered available (that is, not already open in the calling process) file descriptor at the time of each allocation."

Answer (score 2):

This code is incorrect:

```
int file_des= open(args[2],  O_CREAT,  0640);
```

Per [the POSIX documentation for `open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) (note the bolded portion - my bolding):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <sys/stat.h>
> #include <fcntl.h>
>
> int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
> int openat(int fd, const char *path, int oflag, ...);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION ...
>
> Values for `oflag` are constructed by a bitwise-inclusive OR of flags
> from the following list, defined in `<fcntl.h>`. **Applications shall
> specify exactly one of the first five values (file access modes) below
> in the value of `oflag`**:
>
> ```
> O_EXEC
>     Open for execute only (non-directory files). The result is unspecified if this flag is applied to a directory.
> O_RDONLY
>     Open for reading only.
> O_RDWR
>     Open for reading and writing. The result is undefined if this flag is applied to a FIFO.
> O_SEARCH
>     Open directory for search only. The result is unspecified if this flag is applied to a non-directory file.
> O_WRONLY
>     Open for writing only.
> ```

Your `open()` call needs to include either `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR` as you are writing to the file:

```
int file_des= open(args[2],  O_CREAT | O_WRONLY,  0640);
```

Comment: This is correct, and I suggest you edit and go one, explicit step further in the answer.  The OP's file is empty _because the `write` fails with EBADF_, because fd #1 (the return of a successful `dup`) was mistakenly opened _read-only_.  As you say, the call to `open` is incorrect because it omits a mandatory flag.  Anything might have happened, but in this case the OP's system probably defines O_RDONLY as 0x0 (as many do), meaning that mistakenly omitting those flags is the same as specifying O_RDONLY.

Comment: @pilcrow What do you mean by "one step further" with an edit?  (And FWIW, `O_RDONLY` is `0` on Linux...)

Answer (score 2):

#### The Problem

The problem here is that the file descriptor which is being assigned to `file_des` isn't really 1.

```c
int test = dup(file_des);
fprintf(stderr, "%d", test);
```

> 3

#### Now, what could the reason be?

The problem is with how you are opening your file. `O_CREAT` creates a file if it does not exist.

There is no specification whether you are opening the file for read, write, or read/write.

Since you are associating your file to the file descriptor of `stdout`, you must use the `O_WRONLY` flag as well.

```c
int file_des = open(args[2],  O_CREAT | O_WRONLY,  0640);
```